# Move Circle in Turbo c++

Tags: c++, bgi

how can we move a circle on the screen in Turbo c++ and without clear device i want to move it from left to right and then to right to left my code is here but it is with clear device which make the screen blink a little so any help???

```
main() {
  int gd=DETECT,gm,col=0; 
  initgraph(&gd,&gm,"../bgi"); 
START: 
  int get = 0;col=40; 
  while(!kbhit()) 
  { 
    rectangle(20,20,getmaxx()-20,getmaxy()-20);
    circle(col,210,20); 
    delay(5); 
    if(col <600 && get == 0) col++; 
    else{ get=1; col--; } 
    cleardevice(); 
    if(col==40) goto START; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You said your code is here, but I don't see it.

Comment: Tell whomever told you to use Turbo C++ to catch up with current millennium.

Comment: main()
{

int gd=DETECT,gm,col=0;

initgraph(&gd,&gm,"../bgi");
START:
int get = 0;col=40;

while(!kbhit())
{

rectangle(20,20,getmaxx()-20,getmaxy()-20);
circle(col,210,20);
delay(5);


if(col <600 && get == 0)
col++;
else{
get=1;
col--;
}
cleardevice();
if(col==40)
goto START;


}
}

Comment: we are learning Cg so it was initial in it thats y basically we are going to switch OpenGl but thats i want to know so i asked it

Comment: I just added the code to your actual post, so that it is at least somewhat readable. I'm sure the formatting is a bit off, I just did enough of it to make some sense of it.

Comment: You could use XOR, but it violates a patent

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I did Turbo-C++ but I have worked on similar cases. If the circle is hollow you can simulate a clear by redrawing it in the background color. That will be quick enough to avoid the blinks.